# how to set and get HttpSession using JSF/Bean (@named)

Tags: jsf, session

When using Servlet/JSP, we get HttpSession from HttpServletRequest, now that I develop an application using JSF/JPA/EJB, I don't know how to set attribute in session (for login exactly) and how to get them, any help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
HttpSession session = (HttpSession) facesContext.getExternalContext().getSession(true);
session.setAttribute("att", att);
```

Comment: what is the difference between getSession(true) and if we set false???

Comment: `getSession(true)` will create new if there is no session. `getSession(false)` will return `null`  if there is no session